# What are the differences between CHECKSUM() and BINARY_CHECKSUM() and when/what are the appropriate usage scenarios?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Again MSDN does not really explain in plain English the exact difference, or the information for when to choose one over the other.

[CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx)

> Returns the checksum value computed over a row of a table, or over a list of expressions. CHECKSUM is intended for use in building hash indexes.

[BINARY_CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx)

> Returns the binary checksum value computed over a row of a table or over a list of expressions. BINARY_CHECKSUM can be used to detect changes to a row of a table.

It does hint that binary checksum should be used to detect row changes, but not why.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out the following blog post that highlights the diferences.

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/05/18/checksum-functions-in-sql-server-2005/

Adding info from this link:

The key intent of the CHECKSUM functions is to build a hash index based on an expression or a column list. If say you use it to compute and store a column at the table level to denote the checksum over the columns that make a record unique in a table, then this can be helpful in determining whether a row has changed or not. This mechanism can then be used instead of joining with all the columns that make the record unique to see whether the record has been updated or not. SQL Server Books Online has a lot of examples on this piece of functionality.

A couple of things to watch out for when using these functions:

You need to make sure that the column(s) or expression order is the same between the two checksums that are being compared else the value would be different and will lead to issues.

We would not recommend using checksum(*) since the value that will get generated that way will be based on the column order of the table definition at run time which can easily change over a period of time. So, explicitly define the column listing.

Be careful when you include the datetime data-type columns since the granularity is 1/300th of a second and even a small variation will result into a different checksum value. So, if you have to use a datetime data-type column, then make sure that you get the exact date + hour/min. i.e. the level of granularity that you want.

There are three checksum functions available to you:

CHECKSUM: This was described above.

CHECKSUM_AGG: This returns the checksum of the values in a group and Null values are ignored in this case. This also works with the new analytic function’s OVER clause in SQL Server 2005.

BINARY_CHECKSUM: As the name states, this returns the binary checksum value computed over a row or a list of expressions. The difference between CHECKSUM and BINARY_CHECKSUM is in the value generated for the string data-types. An example of such a difference is the values generated for “DECIPHER” and “decipher” will be different in the case of a BINARY_CHECKSUM but will be the same for the CHECKSUM function (assuming that we have a case insensitive installation of the instance). 
Another difference is in the comparison of expressions. BINARY_CHECKSUM() returns the same value if the elements of two expressions have the same type and byte representation. So, “2Volvo Director 20” and “3Volvo Director 30” will yield the same value, however the CHECKSUM() function evaluates the type as well as compares the two strings and if they are equal, then only the same value is returned.

```
Example:
STRING              BINARY_CHECKSUM_USAGE    CHECKSUM_USAGE
------------------- ----------------------    -----------
2Volvo Director 20  -1356512636                -341465450
3Volvo Director 30  -1356512636                -341453853
4Volvo Director 40  -1356512636                -341455363
```

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because he posted the link.  Kuya's answer is a copy&paste from this site.

Comment: So it will be better until the link rots, then it will be worse.

Comment: This link is blocked by my network security. Can anyone copy&paste the answer from this site?

Comment: I found John Sansom's examples of overlapping checksums to be a bit odd.  I suggest users curious about his overlap examples to compute `BINARY_CHECKSUM` and `CHECKSUM` on the following strings: `'00000000000000000000000000000000'`,
`'00000000000000010000000000000001'`,
`'00000000000000000000000000000001'`,
`'00000000000000010000000000000000'`,
`'00000000000000100000000000000000'` .  It's not a coincidence that I chose 32 character strings.

Comment: In my installation, CHECKSUM also returns an identical value for all of those three examples.

Answer (score 9):

HASHBYTES with MD5 is 5 times slower than CHECKSUM, I've tested this on a table with over 1 million rows, and ran each test 5 times to get an average.

Interestingly CHECKSUM takes exactly the same time as BINARY_CHECKSUM.

Here is my post with the full results published:
http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/binary_checksum-vs-hashbytes-in-sql/

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

I've found that checksum collisions (i.e. two different values returning the same checksum) are more common than most people seem to think. We have a table of currencies, using the ISO currency code as the PK. And in a table of less than 200 rows, there are three pairs of currency codes that return the same Binary_Checksum():

- "ETB" and "EUR" (Ethiopian Birr and Euro) both return 16386.
- "LTL" and "MDL" (Lithuanian Litas and Moldovan leu) both return 18700.
- "TJS" and "UZS" (Somoni and Uzbekistan Som) both return 20723.

The same happens with ISO culture codes: "de" and "eu" (German and Basque) both return 1573.

Changing Binary_Checksum() to Checksum() fixes the problem in these cases...but in other cases it may not help. So my advice is to test thoroughly before relying too heavily on the uniqueness of these functions.

Comment: Not a criticism, but a caution: the opposite can be true. There are cases where checksum() will produce collisions but Binary_Checksum() will not, so don't take this advice as universal: " the values generated for “DECIPHER” and “decipher” will be different in the case of a BINARY_CHECKSUM but will be the same for the CHECKSUM function"

Comment: @AarasonLS : We can have duplicate with Binary_CheckSum. Verify this example : SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(16   ,'EP30461105',1) AS BinaryCheckSumEx
UNION ALL
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(21   ,'EP30461155',1) AS BinaryCheckSumEx

Answer (score 5):

Be careful when using CHECSUM, you may get un-expected outcome. the following statements produce the same checksum value;

```
SELECT CHECKSUM (N'这么便宜怎么办？廉价iPhone售价再曝光', 5, 4102)
SELECT CHECKSUM (N'PlayStation Now – Sony startet Spiele-Streaming im Sommer 2014', 238, 13096)
```

Comment: That's expected. Checksum should not be used for uniqueness but for narrowing down the search space.

Answer (score 2):

Its easy to get collisions from CHECKSUM(). HASHBYTES() was added in SQL 2005 to enhance SQL Server's system hash functionality so I suggest you also look into this as an alternative.

Comment: Greg, it would be useful to know the exact differences so one could make an informed decision about the problem at hand.  I have already solved my problem but had issues finding more in-depth information so I created this SO page for others with more complex problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can get checksum value through this query:

```
SELECT
  checksum(definition) as Checksum_Value,
  definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = object_id('RefCRMCustomer_GetCustomerAdditionModificationDetail');
```

replace your proc name in the bracket.