# Find binary duplicate records SQL Server 2008 (Data type image)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have inherited a database that has a table (300gb) full of SQL datatype `Image`. I understand this datatype is depreciated.

As a routine cleanup I want to delete all duplicate `Image`'s from the table where certain conditions are met.

How do I compare binary data using SQL efficiently? Is the = equality operator sufficient?

Here is a scenario:

```
Table 'Paperwork'
  int ID
  int EmployeeID
  int AnotherID
  int AnotherFKID
  image Attachment
```

I want to find all rows where the `Attachment`, `EmployeeID`, `AnotherID` and `AnotherFKID` are the same. It needs to be done with minimal impact on the database as there are over 1,116,313 rows.

**Edit**

The SQL Server `Image` data type does not support `LIKE` or the usual comparison operators.

**Edit**

Thanks to @Martin who suggested the `Image` be casted to varbinary. I have added to this to get the MD5 checksum using Hashbytes

`HASHBYTES('MD5',CAST(cast([Attachment] as varbinary(max))as varbinary)) AS AttachmentMD5`

Comment: How many duplicates are there on average for an `EmployeeID`, `AnotherID`,`AnotherFKID` combination? i.e. On average how many images will need to be compared?

Comment: For this month, 3384. Its a really messy task. The data goes back 10 years and could be 50% duplicates. A bad data entry tool is to blame. The data currently takes up 300gb of space.

Comment: 3384 within each `EmployeeID`,`AnotherID`, `AnotherFKID` group on average? In that case you would probably be better [calculating a checksum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240425/what-are-the-differences-between-checksum-and-binary-checksum-and-when-what-a) for each up front to reduce the number of actual comparisons to make. You would need to cast the `image` to `varbinary(max)` to check equality of those with the same checksums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeremy,

Any all in one script will kill the buffer cache when it reads in the 300g. Break the job down into several tasks.

Task 1

- create a table with the `ID` and a grouping to show duplicates of the three int columns

Table example

```
    TableID  PaperWorkID GroupID
       1        14          1
       2        15          1
       3        21          2
       4        55          2
```

Now we know `PaperWorkID`s 14 and 15 share the same the three int columns because they are in the same group.

Task 2

- add a column (`bigint`) to the table and populate the column with the `DATALENGTH` of the Image column in table `Paperwork` based on the `PaperWorkID` in the table
- remove all non duplicates based on the datalength and `GroupID`

Task 3

- Add a column `varbinary(max)` to the table.
- fill the column with the MD5 hash of the image column based on the `PaperWorkID` in the table
- Remove all non duplicates from the table based on the MD5 hash and the `GroupID`

Task 4

- make 2 backups of the `PaperWork` table
- remove duplicate records in `Paperwork` based on the items remaining in the table.

If the data for the image column was scanned from paper there is very little chance two scans will produce the exact same image. If the data was uploaded twice then you are in luck.