# what is binary_checksum in SQL? and how does it work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand `binary_checksum` and how it works in this scenario,

Value for `a` and `b` is its their `ASCII values(97,98)` but `ab` and `ac` is returning some other `values (1650,1651)`.

The query is,

```
    select binary_checksum(7), id,binary_checksum('a'), binary_checksum('b'), 
binary_checksum('ab'), binary_checksum('ad') from employees;
```

How does it work ? Please explain.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx.

Comment: Here is a very nice intro: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/01/sql-server-introduction-to-binary_checksum-and-working-example/ and read this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240425/what-are-the-differences-between-checksum-and-binary-checksum-and-when-what

Answer (score 1):

BINARY_CHECKSUM usually used to detect changes in a row. If any row has any value changed, this function can be used to figure out if the values are changed in the rows.
However, if the row is changed from A to B and once again changed back to A, the BINARY_CHECKSUM cannot be used to detect the changes.

Hope you already check this.
[binary_checksum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql)

[binary_checksum-and-working-example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/01/sql-server-introduction-to-binary_checksum-and-working-example/)

[Alternative to Binary_CheckSum :Using HASHBYTES() to compare columns](https://web.archive.org/web/20180323185801/http://www.bidn.com/blogs/TomLannen/bidn-blog/2265/using-hashbytes-to-compare-columns)

[checksum-functions-in-sql-](https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/05/18/checksum-functions-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: My main moto is to achieve the same functionality in netezza ? Thats why i am trying to understand this ! can anyone help on this ?